# Python iteration on list

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, indexing, iteration

I've got this example

```
a='Datenfernübertragung remote data transmission|long-distance data transmission|long-distance data transfer|remote data transmission   Preferred|Forbidden|Forbidden|'
b = a.split('\t')
for item in b[1].split('|'):
  indeks=b[1].split('|').index(item)
  print(indeks)
```

and it returns at this moment `0, 1, 2, 0` which are indexes of `remote data transmission|long-distance data transmission|long-distance data transfer|remote data transmission` but why it return to index 0, instead of printing index 3?

Thanks

Comment: Look into `enumerate` if you're trying to get the index

Comment: Because `index` finds the first instance of something. The first instance of `remote data transmission` in the split is the first element of the split.

Comment: Shaun can you post this as an answer, enumerate solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:11:57) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a='Datenfernübertragung remote data transmission|long-distance data transmission|long-distance data transfer|remote data transmission   Preferred|Forbidden|Forbidden|'
>>> b = a.split('\t')
>>> b
['Datenfernübertragung remote data transmission|long-distance data transmission|long-distance data transfer|remote data transmission   Preferred|Forbidden|Forbidden|']
>>> b[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There is no any *\t* in your string, b is a single-item list and its index is zero. Thus your code snippet is completely wrong.

As I could understand you've took an attempt to derive indexes for vertical bar separated values in the string. Hope this snippet should do it in a much neat way:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(a.split('|')):
...     print(i, j)
... 
0 Datenfernübertragung remote data transmission
1 long-distance data transmission
2 long-distance data transfer
3 remote data transmission   Preferred
4 Forbidden
5 Forbidden
6
```